# Symbolicating iOS crash log lines containing libswiftcore.dylib

Tags: ios, swift, crash

Trying to debug an iOS crash (iOS8.4) but after symbolicating the log, the lines for libswiftCore.dylib don't make much sense. Does anyone know how to symbolicate lines 0-2 below?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010089d474
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000010089d474 0x1007dc000 + 791668
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001007fd288 0x1007dc000 + 135816
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001007fd1e4 0x1007dc000 + 135652
3   ImpliciTunes                    0x000000010018e7f0 ImpliciTunes.QueryGenerator.prepareNewContextList (ImpliciTunes.QueryGenerator)([ImpliciTunes.FuzzyContextModelOutput]) -> () (QueryGenerator.swift:131)
4   ImpliciTunes                    0x000000010018f214 ImpliciTunes.QueryGenerator.processNewSensorState (ImpliciTunes.QueryGenerator)(force : Swift.Bool) -> () (QueryGenerator.swift:173)
5   ImpliciTunes                    0x0000000100190668 ImpliciTunes.QueryGenerator.indoorOutdoorStateUpdated (ImpliciTunes.QueryGenerator)(Swift.Int) -> () (QueryGenerator.swift:207)
6   ImpliciTunes                    0x00000001001906ac @objc ImpliciTunes.QueryGenerator.indoorOutdoorStateUpdated (ImpliciTunes.QueryGenerator)(Swift.Int) -> () (QueryGenerator.swift:0)
7   ImpliciTunes                    0x000000010011dc18 ImpliciTunes.IndoorOutdoor.hysterisisTimerExpired (ImpliciTunes.IndoorOutdoor)(ObjectiveC.NSTimer) -> () (IndoorOutdoor.swift:202)
8   ImpliciTunes                    0x000000010011dcd4 @objc ImpliciTunes.IndoorOutdoor.hysterisisTimerExpired (ImpliciTunes.IndoorOutdoor)(ObjectiveC.NSTimer) -> () (IndoorOutdoor.swift:0)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I was able to symbolicate it using Crashlytics - didn't do it manually.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Using hockeyapp instead of crashlytics and the libswiftCore.dylib parts are never symbolicated. The dsyms for the app and frameworks seem to be generated correctly. Is there some build setting I am missing? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Before sharing the app make sure your app uploaded with the bitcode, you can track easily the crash report using dsym file downloaded from iTunes and archived from xcode.

For more details go this referencing url

[e[For more click her](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html